# ipython notebook missing header/toolbar/menubar

Tags: python, ipython

Although others are looking for ways to hide the menubar or header of ipython notebook, I found my ipython notebook comes with no header, no toolbar, no menubar, and I tried to add the following script to the `custom.js`, but still, nothing shows up

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
$('div#header').show();
$('div#maintoolbar').show();
$('#header-container').show();
});
```

I tried Ipython 3.0, 3.2, Firefox, Chrome, none helps. I am using Python3.4, 64bit on Windows 7.

I also enclosed a screenshot to show what I have on my notebook.
[image: ipython notebook no header]

Comment: Can you post sur custom.css ? In my template bars are hidden on purpose in the CSS.

Comment: Also, open your browser's JS console and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: it is just the default custom.js, same as the one shown here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/master/custom.example.js, almost everything is commented out. and i dont see errors in JS console

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install jupyterthemes
import jupyterthemes as jt

!jt -r
```

this will throw the output like this

Reset css and font defaults in: /Users/malaudeen/.jupyter/custom & /Users/malaudeen/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions

Finally

refresh your browser.